# Me da como respuesta el texto incorrecto

Tags: c++, booleano

Tengo que hacer un programa en el que me diga si un numero es perfecto, Ejemplo: 6 es perfecto porque 6 = 1+2+3. Soy bastante nuevo así que ténganme paciencia, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool EsPerfecto(int num);

int main(){
    int n;
    bool sumadivisor;
    cout << "Digite numero para comprobar si es perfecto: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    sumadivisor = EsPerfecto(n);
    if(sumadivisor) {
        cout << "Es perfecto." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No es perfecto." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
bool EsPerfecto(int num)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i == 0)
    return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El fallo principal que veo es que la función `EsPerfecto` no devuelve si un número es perfecto o no, simplemente va incrementando la variable `i` de 1 en 1 y comprueba si el siguiente valor de `i` es módulo del número introducido. Esto quiere decir que si metes cualquier número te dirá siempre `true` porque el módulo 1 de cualquier número es siempre 0 y el valor de `i` comienza siempre en 1 en el bucle.

Además de que tienes puestos los dos `return` dentro de la comprobación del `for`, de forma que ya directamente el primer valor que comprueba del `for` será decisivo para que salga del bucle y no podrá comprobar los siguientes (Por ejemplo, en caso de que empieces por `i=2` te devolverá `false` siempre que `num` sea impar porque no pasará del primer caso)

Una posible solución sería modificar la función `EsPerfecto` por otra que vaya acumulando el valor de `i` en otra variable y sea esa variable nueva la que se compruebe si es igual al número introducido:

```
bool EsPerfecto(int num)
{
    int i;
    vector<int> divisores;
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0)
            divisores.push_back(i);
    }
    int sumRes = 0;
    for (int divisor : divisores) {
        sumRes += divisor;
    }
    if (num == sumRes)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Probablemente haya soluciones más optimizadas pero esta es la solución más rápida que he podido proporcionarte dado el código que has pasado, simplemente modifica tu función `EsPerfecto` por esta nueva y debería ir.

**EDIT:** Con esta nueva modificación he utilizado la clase vector para acumular los divisores, podrías utilizar cualquier otra de la stl o utilizar la tuya propia, en este caso bastaría con añadir `#include <vector>` al principio del código.

Comment: La funcion no determina si es un numero perfecto. El primer numero perfecto es
el 6, y el siguiente es el 28. Tu funcion da falsos positivos en el 10, 15 y 21.

Comment: @Pablochaches me había limitado a la definición dada en la pregunta en lugar de la matemáticamente correcta, ya está corregida.